# How to connect HP F1903 monitor to MacBook Pro?

Tags: display

I connected my HP Pavilion F1903 monitor to my MacBook Pro using the Rocketfish adapter I purchased from the Apple salesman at Best Buy.  The monitor is turned on, but what's showing up on my laptop screen is not appearing on the monitor.  How do I get my laptop to talk to my external monitor?

PS:  My monitor is probably 7 years old, and my MacBookPro is less than 2 years old.

Comment: Which os, and which adapter i.e. DVI to HDMI?

Comment: Do you get _any_ image - background color changes - anything?